# Applying different overrides of _form.html.erb first to New, then to Edit views in Spree Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, spree, deface

I am new to Rails. I wish to apply 2 overrides in order to vary display of a Promotions object in its New and Edit views. The overrides are listed below. Both overrides work correctly, by themselves.

But I cannot figure out how to apply one override to the New view, then the second to the Edit view.

How can I apply a different override to each of the New and to the Edit views?

Currently my Promotion object is created saved successfully, but its values are not then displayed in the edit view. Furthermore, the edit view is rendered identically to the New view, which is wrong.

Code:

Using Spree Deface, I override a promotions form (_form.html.erb) to yield a New (Create) view like so:

```
 Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/admin/promotions/_form",
                 :name => "example-3",
                 :replace => "div.row",
                 :partial => "shared/new_promotion"
 )
```

In a second override, I override _form.html.erb thus:

```
 Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/admin/promotions/_form",
                 :name => "example-3",
                 :replace => "div.row",
                 :partial => "shared/uploadcsvfile"
 )
```

These overrides currently sit in the same directly.

Answer (score 0):

There are separate forms for the new and edit actions.  Both include the form partial as shown in the [new view](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/d375f7967328a52ab260083cb16a3f2d5c8d8aa1/backend/app/views/spree/admin/promotions/new.html.erb#L13) and [edit view](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/d375f7967328a52ab260083cb16a3f2d5c8d8aa1/backend/app/views/spree/admin/promotions/edit.html.erb#L13).

You want to show different content based upon whether you are in the new or edit view, so you'll have to decide the following:

> Based upon information that I know within the form, how can I determine if the form was drawn from within the edit form, or from within the new form.

There are two easy possibilities that I can see:

1. Check if the form method is POST, or PUT/PATCH.  If it's post, the form is intended for the create action (i.e. from new), or if it's PUT/PATCH it's intended for update (edit).
2. Check if `@promotion` is persisted.  If it is persisted, it is an edit action, otherwise it is a new action.

You can do those checks in your new partials and render the appropriate content.